# Storing ACF repeater values as one single array in the database

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I have a complex Advanced Custom Fields repeater with, in each row, dozens of subfields in different groups.
The repeater usually doesn’t have that many rows (10-15 max), but that’s still hundreds of values added in the database for each post, which is starting to hurt performance on the admin side.

So I’m wondering: instead of creating one database entry for each subfield of the repeater, is it possible to have all the repeater values stored as one array in the database? The same array that is generated when doing get_field(‘my_repeater’).

I'm aware that by doing this, the repeater values probably won't be displayed on the next page load, but I can always reconstruct the repeater from the array with JS, i don't mind putting in the work.